# How can I hide the Terminal split pane scroll bar?

Tags: macos

**Edit:** I realised that this wasn't Terminal specific and found the answer.

[image]

This toolbar/scrollbar appeared permanently all of a sudden for some reason, and I'd like to hide it, but can't find an option to do so?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you've probably figured, I'm not used to using a mouse and realised that's what's causing the problem.

[image]